# Maintaing test users in cucumber steps

Tags: csv, cucumber

In my tests I have to work with different types of users and environments. At the moment I am manually updating the users since we don't have many features. However we will be adding many new features that will make it very difficult to update all files manually. Most of these are needed in the Given step. Example:

```
Scenario:
  Given I am signed in as "user1@example.com"
```

I would like to change this to:

```
Scenario
  Given I am signed in as "user1"
```

"user1" could stored in a csv file or in a db. Can either of these be done? If so which is the recommended method?

The CSV file would have something like:

```
user1,user1@example.com
user2,user2@example.com
user3,user3@example.com
```

A table in a db:

```
| id | user  | email             |
| 1  | user1 | user1@example.com |
| 2  | user2 | user2@example.com |
```

Seems using the db might be easier to maintain if it can be done. As always your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to abstract test case details in Cucumber is through the use of "Scenario Outlines":

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines

Using a Scenario Outline is equivalent to storing test case data in a CSV file, but it has the advantage of keeping the test case info right there in the .feature file.

If you follow this convention, all parts of the test workflow can be edited in the same place - this actually makes maintenance of the test cases easier than if the test outline and the individual test cases are segregated into separate text files (or segregated between a .feature file and a database instance).